# Method sscanf() ambiguous behavior

Tags: c

I am trying to understand how `sscanf()` works. I ran some examples from this page: http://docs.roxen.com/pike/7.0/tutorial/strings/sscanf.xml and they don't work on my platform. I can't understand why. 
For instance: "sscanf("4711bar", "%d%s", a, b);" makes the program exit with an error...

Here is one of the examples that work: "sscanf("foo", "f%s", a);".
Does anybody know why? Do they work on your platforms? Thank you.

This is my code:

```
 int main(void){

   char *b = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);       
   int a = 0;

   sscanf("4711bar", "%d%s", a, b);
   printf("%d", a);
   printf("%s", b);
 }
```

Comment: I bet you don't pass valid pointers to variables...

Comment: The documentation you are looking at **is not for C or C++ but for an entirely different language**.

Comment: Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: @CarmenCojocaru Because it is an error to do so, and you don't want to have errors in your code (care to read the answer behind the link?)

Comment: @H2CO3 This comes from the same article: "True. However, in C++ the cast is required, so if you want your code to work in **both**, you'll have to compromise. But in pure C, don't do the cast for the reasons you stated. "

Comment: @CarmenCojocaru But no sane programmer uses `malloc()` in C++. In C++, one uses `vector` or at most `operator new[]`. If you *need* the cast, that indicates that you are doing something terribly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write: `sscanf("4711bar", "%d%s", &a, b);`
The `&` makes `&a` is **a pointer** to `a` and `sscanf` requires pointers.

The second example works, because `a` is an array. And array `a` of type `char[100]` is implictly converted to pointer of type `char *`  pointing to the array's first element (`a[0]`). So `a` is the same as `&(a[0])`

```
int a;
char b[100];
sscanf("4711bar", "%d%s", &a, b);
```

-

```
char a[100];
sscanf("foo", "%s", a);
```

Comment: Why it doesn't work with a pointer to char, like char *b and it does with an array of chars?

Comment: "And name of array is pointer to its first element." - it isn't, but it is **implicitly converted into** a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @CarmenCojocaru Because the uninitialized pointer doesn't point to any valid memory.

Comment: @Zifre No problem, it's a mistake easy to make. (At least you didn't insist! How many people do...)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass valid pointers to `sscanf`, `&a` for integer and `b` for string:

```
sscanf("4711bar", "%d%s", &a, b);
                          ^
```

Moreover, your code is C-ish not C++. Using C++ it should looks something like:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "4711bar";

int a;
std::string b;

s >> a >> b;
```